# Create "virtual" data on query?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I hope the title is more or less alright, didn't know how to describe my problem.

What I would like to do is to create a timeseries of dates that are between to dates that the user can chose, without actually saving the dates to a table. Let's say it is 15th Nov 2014 and 16th Nov 2014 I would like to have a query that gives me:

```
[date]
11-15-2014 00:00
11-15-2014 01:00
11-15-2014 02:00
..
11-15-2014 23:00
```

Is there any way to create those dates with a query (and maybe a table containing the start date) only?

I thougt about something like

```
SELECT Dateadd('h', i, t1.start_date) as date FROM t1
```

and then some part saying "i" will be between 0 and DateDiff('h', start_date, end_date)

I know this would be easy if there where temporary variables availabe, which unfortunately is not the case on MS Access.

Right now I'm using a workaround, where I have a table containing the date value of each hour for a few years and where I use a LEFT JOIN ... WHERE date BETWEEN, but I don't like this "dirty" trick much.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your 'dirty' trick is actualy quite normal and good solution. For hours you could use not single, but two additional tables - one record per each day in first and 24 records (for each hour) in another table.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do it, but it also is a bit 'dirty':

```
select d.BaseDay, h.Hour, DateAdd(HH, h.Hour, d.BaseDay)
from
(
    select convert(datetime, '15 Nov 2014') BaseDay
    union select dateadd(D, 1, convert(datetime, '15 Nov 2014'))
    union select dateadd(D, 2, convert(datetime, '15 Nov 2014'))
    union select dateadd(D, 3, convert(datetime, '15 Nov 2014'))
    union select dateadd(D, 4, convert(datetime, '15 Nov 2014'))
    union select dateadd(D, 5, convert(datetime, '15 Nov 2014'))
    union select dateadd(D, 6, convert(datetime, '15 Nov 2014'))
    union select dateadd(D, 7, convert(datetime, '15 Nov 2014'))
    union select dateadd(D, 8, convert(datetime, '15 Nov 2014'))
    union select dateadd(D, 9, convert(datetime, '15 Nov 2014'))
    union select dateadd(D, 10, convert(datetime, '15 Nov 2014'))
    union select dateadd(D, 11, convert(datetime, '15 Nov 2014'))
    -- continue for as many days as you want
    -- to cover the max period you'll want
) d
cross join
(
    select 0 Hour
    union select 1
    union select 2
    union select 3
    union select 4
    union select 5
    union select 6
    -- continuing up to hour 23 excluded for brevity
) h
where d.BaseDay < '16 Nov 2014'
```

The two hard-coded dates would be parameters (@startDate and @endDate) in a proper implementation.

The two drawbacks: 
The number of days between start and end date is limited to how-ever many you can stand typing (11 in this case), and Clock-change days are not catered for at all.

One advantage: While this will take some resources from the SQL Server to run, it will generate no disc access at all, and so will be fairly fast and not affect any other queries which do require disc accesses.

I don't necessarily recommend this. I just note that it is possible.

Comment: You syntax would not work in MS Access (note tags by OP), although general idea is implementable. Well, for big timespans (over years or so) I think MS Access query engine will fail with such union anyway.

Comment: I didn't notice the Access tag. And for more than a couple of days or weeks I wouldn't recommend this method.